# ol3-cesium polygon float

Tags: polygon, drape

I'm trying to build a web map using ol3-cesium libraries, when I switch 2d map to 3d map my polygons (GeoJSON or GeoServer WMS, WFS) are not draped on stk-terrain but they are under the ground. I tried to use geometry data both in EPSG:3857 that in EPSG:4326, but my polygons still remain under the ground.

I tried to load my polygons (WMS and GeoJSON) on the ol3-cesium example
 http://openlayers.org/ol3-cesium/examples/epsg-4326.html on the 2d map they are correctly located but when I switch to 3d map the geometries disappear. Unfortunately, I cannot understand why, if it is only a coordinates problem.

I think I know OpenLayers use EPSG:3857 and automatically projects the geometries to EPSG:4326, so it makes no difference to have the data in EPSG:3857 or EPSG:4326, for Cesium libraries it’s the same?

This is an excerpt of my code:

```
    _myStroke_ghiacciai = new ol.style.Stroke({
               color : 'rgba(0,0,255,1.0)',
               width : 0.8 
            });

            _myFill_ghiacciai  = new ol.style.Fill({
               color: 'rgba(0,0,255,0.2)'
            });

            myStyle_ghiacciai  = new ol.style.Style({
               stroke : _myStroke_ghiacciai ,
               fill : _myFill_ghiacciai    
             });    
var ghiacciai = new ol.layer.Vector({  
                                    title: 'Ghiacciai',
                                    visible: true,
                                    source: new ol.source.Vector({
                                    url: 'data/ghiacciai.json',
                                    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
                                    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
                                            }) ,
                                            style: myStyle_ghiacciai        });

view = new ol.View({
         projection: 'EPSG:3857', 
         center: ol.proj.transform([9.5, 46.1], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
          zoom: 8,
          maxZoom: 14,
          minZoom: 7
          zoomFactor: 2 
          });   
    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map', 
        controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
            new ol.control.ScaleLine(),  
            new ol.control.ZoomSlider(),
]),
        renderer: 'canvas', 
         layers: [
            new ol.layer.Group({
                'title': 'Base maps'
                layers: [

                new ol.layer.Tile({                                 title: 'Ortofoto con strade',   
                                type: 'base',
                                visible: false,
                                source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                                    url: 'http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/digitalglobe.nmmigejm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGlnaXRhbGdsb2JlIiwiYSI6ImNpZnB2bWUzNDZoczlzaWtxMmd2bDc3ZHQifQ.AHiF6mR5aXL0rdI4eLz2dA', // You will need to replace the 'access_token' and 'Map ID' values with your own. http://developer.digitalglobe.com/docs/maps-api
                attribution: "© DigitalGlobe, Inc"
                                })
                }),


                new ol.layer.Tile({
                        title: 'Ortofoto',
                        type: 'base',
                        visible: false,
                        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                                    attributions: [
                                    new ol.Attribution({
                                            html: 'Tiles &copy; <a href="http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/' +
                                            'rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer">ArcGIS</a>'
                                                    })
                                    ],
                                    url: 'http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/' +
                                    'World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'
                                                })
                    }),
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                        title: 'Topografica',

                        type: 'base',
                        visible: true,   
                        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                                    attributions: [
                                    new ol.Attribution({
                                            html: 'Tiles &copy; <a href="http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/' +
                                            'rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer">ArcGIS</a>'    })],url: 'http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/' +'World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'})
                    }),
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                        title: 'Stradario',
                        type: 'base',
                        visible: false,
                        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    attributions: [new ol.Attribution({
html: 'Tiles &copy; <a href="http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/' +
                                    'rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer">ArcGIS</a>'   }  ],
url: 'http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/' +
'World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'  })})
                ]  }),          
            new ol.layer.Group({
                title: 'Overlays',
                layers: [ghiacciai ] })   ],
        view: view });

    var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
     tipLabel: 'Legenda' 
     });
    map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
var zoomToExtentControl = new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({
        label: 'Home',
        extent:[1007934.024, 5888053.048,  1190159.773, 5768785.981],
        target: document.getElementById('home')
        });
        map.addControl(zoomToExtentControl);

    var ol3d = new olcs.OLCesium({map: map});

    var scene = ol3d.getCesiumScene();
    var terrainProvider = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
        url : '//assets.agi.com/stk-terrain/world',
        requestWaterMask : true,
        requestVertexNormals : false
    });
    scene.terrainProvider = terrainProvider;
    ol3d.setEnabled(false);
```